# Session expiration timeout

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Here, I am setting session expire in codeigniter, in config file like this,

```
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
```

But, It is expired before 2 hours, So, where is the problem actual?

Comment: What version of CI you using.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do that before the session library is loaded, since it reads the config in the constructor, and copies it to internal variables. So modifying it after the fact is pointless.

Source:
http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-31039.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you not only set `sess_expiration`, but also set `sess_time_to_update` correctly.

See discussion here: [relation between sess_expiration and sess_time_to_update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727375/relation-between-sess-expiration-and-sess-time-to-update-with-ajax-call-in-codei)

Hope this helps - Good luck! :)